# Using Custom Log Service In Custom Filter With Dependecy Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection

In my ASP.NET Core API application, I have developed a Custom Filter called ValidateFilterAttribute to check whether requests are valid or not. (FluentValidation)

Here, if the request is not valid, I want to use the my custom Log service. However, I want to inject this Log service using Dependency Injection.

I have added my `ValidateFilterAttribute` class in the Program.cs as follows:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(
            new ValidateFilterAttribute(builder.Configuration)
        );
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

And Log Service:

```
services.AddScoped<IBaseLogService, FileAndDatabaseLogService>();
```

Now, how can I use my Log service with DI in my `ValidateFilterAttribute` class?

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in [this Microsoft documentation on DI and filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#dependency-injection). Short answer is, call `options.Filters.AddService<T>()`.

Comment: Are you expecting switch service after container is built

Answer (score 0):

> use my Log service with DI in my ValidateFilterAttribute class

```
    public class ValidateFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IBaseLogService _baseLogService;

        public ValidateFilterAttribute(IBaseLogService baseLogService)
        {
            this._baseLogService = baseLogService;
        }
        ...
```